List webform user submissions in user profile of logged in user (not administrator)
Using Webform Version: 6.3.0-alpha2 with Webform Demo: Application/Evaluation System on Drupal 10.3.10
I am using the "Demo: Application" webform and I created 2 jobs, Doctor and Nurse, for jobseekers to apply to.
I create a user role called jobseeker with access to "View own submissions" (/admin/structure/webform/manage/demo_application/access)
I create 2 test users Jack and Jill under the jobseeker role.
If Jack applies to both jobs (Doctor and Nurse) I want him to see both submissions when he logs in.
Let's says Jacks user id is 3.
An Administrator can see Jack's submissions at https://example.com/user/3/submissions but how does Jack see ALL his submissions when logged in? If Jack logs in he gets Access Denied at https://example.com/user/3/submissions
I am aware that if Jack tries to apply to same job twice he gets a notification like "You have already submitted this webform. View your previous submission." at a url similar to https://example.com/node/36/webform/submissions/28 BUT I want Jack to see ALL his submissions across all the jobs he applied and not just 1.
Is there a setting I need to check? Using Olivero 10.3.10 (default theme). Googling suggest https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views may help but I don't see how.
Help appreciated.
Thank you

Solved: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3066413 -  enable the "Access the webform user submission page" permission (under /admin/people/permissions),

I recommend accepting your own answer :)
